# Formula to determine latest ordered entry of unique table values

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm looking for some help in creating a column populated with 1's for the (in this example) 'latest' revision of each unique entry (in another column).

```
Project #   Rev    Flag
=========================
  FCA1       A  
  FCA1       D       1
  FCA1       B  
  FCA1       B  
  FCA1       C  
  FCA1       C  
  BRS1       A  
  BRS1       B       1
  BRS2       A       1
  FCA2       A  
  FCA2       A  
  FCA2       B  
  FCA2       B  
  FCA2       C       1
  FCA2       C       1
  BRS3       A       1
  FCA1       D       1
  FCA1       D       1
  FCA1       A
```

My desired output is in the 'Flag' column in the above example. For example, all Rev D's for project number FCA1 and all Rev C's for FCA2. Same thing for the other values under Project #. Note that I'd like this done independent of the order or sorting of the entries. The example just happens to show them in some sort of order for clarity.

I'm working with Excel 2010.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The formula you want is:

`=IF(MAX(INDEX(($A$2:$A$20=$A2)*CODE($B$2:$B$20),0))=CODE($B2),1,"")`

E.g.:

[image]

### EDIT

Re the question *how can I error handle when there is a blank entry in the Rev column?* It's not possible if you are using `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` as revision codes because the `CODE` function won't handle an empty string in the formula I presented. If you switch to number-based revisions then it will work with this formula:

```
=IF(MAX(INDEX(($A$2:$A$20=$A2)*$B$2:$B$20,0))=$B2,1,"")
```

Noting that this is the same formula as above but without the `CODE` function usage. E.g. if `A=1`, `B=2`, `C=3` and `D=4` then:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. It works as expected, but how can I error handle when there is a blank entry in the Rev column? I'd like for the corresponding Final column entry blank and the rest of the Final column unaffected.